# Getting error after editing web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I added the content query web part in one of my subsites but after I done the editing and click 'ok', the site has turned into page error.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the snap shot of error? or error text?